# How to match two strings from separate lists - Posix Shell

Tags: linux, shell, posix

I have a POSIX shell script that tries to find manual install paths for tomcat on an ubuntu (20.04) system. I run `dpkg-query` to make a list of installs that were installed using the package manager. Then I iterate over a list of common install paths. If any of the installs found using `dpkg-query` match, I need to exclude those from my discovery. But, I can't seem to figure out an efficient way to do this.

Code:

```
#/bin/sh
  
APP="Apache Tomcat"

# Common install paths to iterate over
set -- "/opt/" "/usr/share/" "/var/" "/var/lib/" "/usr/" "/usr/local/" 

# Create exclusion list for managed installs from apt and yum
EXCLUSION_LIST=""

if [ -x "$(command -v dpkg-query)" ]; then
    dpkg_check=$(dpkg-query -l | grep -Eo 'tomcat[0-9]?' | sort -u)
    EXCLUSION_LIST=$dpkg_check
    echo $EXCLUSION_LIST

    # Check for manual installs
    for _i in "$@"; do
        find_tomcat=$(ls $_i | grep -E '^tomcat[0-9]{0,2}$')
        excluded_list=$(echo $EXCLUSION_LIST)
        for match in $excluded_list; do
            if [ $find_tomcat == $match ]; then
                echo "$match is excluded"
            else
                echo $_i$find_tomcat
        done
    done

else
    echo "DPKG not found."    
fi
```

Desired Output:

Install path of manual version not installed by the package manager.

E.g., `/usr/share/tomcat`

Comment: `POSIX shell script ... an ubuntu (20.04)` why do you limit yourself on ubuntu? First check your script with shellcheck.net . Do not parse ls.

Comment: Why not just `if command -v dpkg-query >/dev/null 2>&1; then` -- no need to create a subshell, capture the output, and pass it as an argument to `[`.

Comment: So there are some paths in `"$@"`. There are system paths in `EXCLUSION_LIST`. You want to exclude `EXCLUSION_LIST` from `"$@"`. Then you want to check if for each of the resulting excluded list there is a `tomcat[0-9]?[0-9]?` directory and get these directories?

Comment: BTW, `/bin/sh` isn't guaranteed to support `==` as a string comparison operator; only `=` is portable across all implementations.

Comment: ...and if you want a portable way to match a string against a pattern, that's what `case` is for. See https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/case

Comment: (Also, there are places where missing quotes can trip you up; http://shellcheck.net/ will identify them).

Comment: Also, this is a place where it would be _really_ worthwhile to use a modern shell. Bash 4.0 and later support associative arrays -- what some other languages call "hashes" or "maps", allowing O(1) lookup for whether a string exists as a key in the structure. Limiting yourself to `sh` is thus making your performance worse.

Answer (score 1):

Observations:

- The first line needs to start literally with the two characters `#!` to be a valid shebang
- You are needlessly copying the same strings to multiple variables, in one place with a [useless `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo)
- Don't use upper case for your private variables; see [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)
- [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)
- [Don't parse `ls` output.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) Instead, I propose looping over wildcard matches in this case.
- Your current logic seems to be basically saying, "if `tomcat8` was installed by `dpkg`, don't print any `tomcat8` paths." I'm guessing you *actually* want to avoid printing paths which are installed by a `dpkg`-installed `tomcat*` package, and print others.
- Your `dpkg-query -l` command is slightly inexact, in that it will find not just package *names,* but also package *descriptions* which contain the search string. You can use `dpkg-query -W` instead, to only print package names and versions.
- `dpkg -L` prints the actual paths installed by a set of packages.

Untested, but hopefully at least a step in the right direction.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# Unused variable
# APP="Apache Tomcat"

if [ -x "$(command -v dpkg-query)" ]; then
    exclusion_list=$(dpkg-query -W | sed -n 's/^\(tomcat[0-9]*\)\t[^\t].*/\1/p' | sort -u)
    echo "$exclusion_list"

    # Check for manual installs
    for _i in "/opt" "/usr/share" "/var" "/var/lib" "/usr" "/usr/local"; do
        for found in "$_i"/tomcat*; do
            case $found in
             */tomcat | */tomcat[0-9] | */tomcat[0-9][0-9] ) ;;
             *) continue;;
            esac
            found_dir=${found%/*}
            if dpkg -L $exclusion_list | fgrep -qx "$found_dir"
            then
                echo "$match is excluded"
            else
                echo "$found"
            fi
        done
    done
else
    echo "DPKG not found."    
fi
```

Comment: After running the code, this is the output: `tomcat8
tomcat9
/opt//tomcat
/opt//tomcat
/opt//tomcat
/usr/share//tomcat8
/usr/share//tomcat8
/usr/share//tomcat8
/usr/share//tomcat8-root
/usr/share//tomcat9
/usr/share//tomcat9
/usr/share//tomcat9
/usr/share//tomcat9-admin`
Maybe I didn't explain correctly, but what I need are JUST the install paths of the version NOT found from dpkg. So, in this case, all it should return is `/opt/tomcat/`

Comment: @cynicalswan77 See updated answer now. I'm still not entirely sure what exactly you want, and I still have no way to test this, but at least now I have my hands on a Debian system where I can experiment.